# Webcrawler and video/audio application with multistream output to user

Tags: video, audio, download-manager, youtube

In short, I'm searching for something that's capable of this:

1. Webcrawling for videos and audio
2. Saving the data
3. Showing this data in multiple streams
4. An user friendly graphical user interface
5. Which runs on Linux (or open source alike) and/or Windows

I'm searching for a kinda specific application. I don't know if it exists, surely because I can't find it. **What I'm searching for** is a sort of multimedia application which is **capable of** *crawling information from specific websites* (audio and video files), *saving them* and *showing them in multiple streams of information*. **What I mean by multiple streams of information is**: if you have two videos playing, one is showing on the left with the sound balance to the left, the other is showing on the right with the sound balance to the right. **I want to be able to** *stop and start all playing streams at the same time* and to *start and stop with one stream at the time*.

**The platform could be** Linux (or any free OS which is *alike*) or Windows.

Does anyone know **if this exists**, **what type of application** this is and **where I can find it**?

**Notes**:

1. It should support youtube.
2. Downloading would be the ideal case, but by services like youtube I don't know if this is legal. So if both can be supported, that's great.

Comment: (1) As you tagged your question with [tag:youtube], the tool has to support downloading from YouTube, correct? Which other sites? (2) You say *stream*, but the tool should download the video/audio and play them locally, correct? Or should the crawler just find the URLs and you want to stream them from the Internet?